# Linear Algebra the Dimension of a Vector Space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm self-studying Linear Algebra and I'm currently studying the dimension of a vector space. These two are from the exercise problems and they confuse me a bit.

1. $\left\{~\begin{bmatrix}s-2t\\s+t\\3t\end{bmatrix} : s,t \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$

so for this problem I just set up a matrix like below.

$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2\\1&1\\0&3\end{bmatrix}$

the two column vectors were linearly independent to each other thus, the dimension to be $2$.

However for this second problem,

2. $\left\{(a,b,c) : a-3b+c=0,b-2c=0,2b-c=0\right\}$

I did exactly the same thing I used the coefficients of $a,b,c$ to set up a matrix
and got the rref of it which turned out to be the identity matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$. So I figured the dimension would be $3$ but the answer was $0$.

What's the difference between them?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: They're described differently. In the first case, you have a set which is all linear combinations of two vectors. In the second case, you are looking for a vector that has certain properties. The math is on "different sides of the colon".

Comment: so for the second problem, I'm trying to find the vectors a,b,c that satisfy the conditions a-3b+c...... like getting an intersection point?

Comment: Have you tried to find an explicit element of the second space?

Comment: @LookAtTheBigPicture Yes.